# Porque E.printStackTrace deve ser removida?

Tags: java, stack-trace

Uso o Try catch da seguinte forma:

```
try{
   //meu código
} catch(Exception E) {
   E.printStackTrace();
}
```

utilizando a IDE netbeans, ele mostra uma dica, chamada "imprimir Rastreamento de Pilha", quando eu clico nele, ele diz ("Throwable.printStackTrace deve ser removido!)

Porque isso?

Existe uma maneira correta de mostrar os erros? já vi por exemplo

```
System.err.println(E.getMessage());
```

ou

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,E.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade alguns IDEs mostram isso como Warning por dois motivos: Ou porque você não está tratando a exceção e simplesmente "repassando" e outra situação por razões de segurança. Se você utilizar alguma ferramenta de análise de código, ela apontará que você não deve simplesmente fazer um e.printStackTrace por diversas razões, principalmente segurança e outra, fazer isso e mostrar em um diálogo para o usuário é preguiça :-)

Trate as exceções cada uma em seu devido lugar. Entenda como funciona a hierarquia de exceções isso ajudará você melhorar muito seu código. No começo eu fazia sempre try catch(Exception e) genérico. Até que um dia eu falei isso aqui tá uma porquice. Resolvi estudar e aprendi que lançar o erro e não tratá-lo não adianta nada e entendi como utilizar tratamento de exceções. Elas servem para que você trate cada situação em específico em sua aplicação. Jamais mostre para o usuário uma exceção nativa sem passar por um tratamento. Vou te dar um exemplo bem simples:

```
public class Operacoes {
  public int dividir(Integer numerador, Integer denominador) {
    if (denominador.equals(0)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominador não pode ser zero");
    }
    return numerador/denominador;
  }
}
```

Ao usar, você poderia fazer:

```
try{
   dividir(10,0);
}catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){
   //como você está tratando propriamente lá no método, poderia ser exibido para o usuário um alerta contendo ex.getMessage();
}
```

Espero ter compreendido. Qualquer dúvida, comente e vamos te ajudando. É um assunto muito legal esse.

Comment: Então, eu faço o tratamento de erros, mostrando ao usuário alguma mensagem ou coisa do tipo quando dá determinados erros, mas mesmo assim, gosto de colocar por exemplo 
    E.printstackTrace(); //para eu saber oq aconteceu
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Alguma Mensagem De erro"));
mas mesmo assim, acho estranho o fato de as IDEs pedirem para retirar o stackTrace